# How to configure a button containing an image in TableViewCell.swift file, and implement showing different images in each table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimageview

I am trying to show a button as an image of restaurant food and a button below that as a text label containing the name of that restaurant all in a custom table view cell. So when you scroll down the table view, you see pictures of different restaurant food and the name of the restaurant below the picture. I have a XIB file I’m using for this.

At the moment, I’m using a `UIImage` for the pictures of the restaurants, and this is working, but I’m trying to instead use a button with an image, so that I can make an `@IBAction` after the picture of the food that is a button is clicked.

I have configured a button showing restaurant names in the `TableViewCell.swift` file as shown below (the labels show when ran):

`TableViewCell.swift` code:

```
@IBOutlet var labelButton: UIButton!

//For retaining title in a property for IBAction use.
private var title: String = ""

func configureLabelButton(with title: String) {
        self.title = title //For retaining title in a property for IBAction use.
        labelButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
}
```

and implemented showing different restaurant names in each table view cell from an array with the restaurant names as strings in the view controller as shown below.

`ViewController.swift` code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RestaurantTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RestaurantTableViewCell

    cell.configureLabelButton(with: myData[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

I am trying to do the same thing for showing an image in a button. I have an array of images I'm using for this same purpose called `myImages`. Here is the code I have so far, but it is not working when run.

`TableViewCell.swift` code:

```
@IBOutlet var imageButton: UIButton!

//For retaining image in a property for IBAction use.
private var image: UIImage = UIImage()

func configureImageButton(with image: UIImage) {
    self.image = image //For retaining image in a property for IBAction use.
    imageButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
}
```

`ViewController.swift` code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RestaurantTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RestaurantTableViewCell

    cell.configureImageButton(with: myImages[indexPath.row]!)
    cell.imageButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 185
}
```

I think my error is somewhere in `TableViewCell.swift`. I think I do not have the correct code there and potentially in `ViewController.swift`.

Comment: *"it is not working when run"* -- do you mean you get an error / crash? Do you mean you don't see any images? Try a little debugging... 1) Does your `myImages` actually contain valid images? 2) If you give `imageButton` a background color in your XIB, do you see the button at the correct size and position?

Comment: Thank you. I mean I don't get an error/crash; the program runs. I don't see any images when using the button for the images. 1) yes, and 2) yes. I think my problem lies in my configureImageButton function in TableViewCell.Swift. I think the code is just wrong, particularly either "image", "setImage", or ".normal".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question. The syntax in TableView.swift was wrong. This may have been due to a Swift update.

Was:

`imageButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)`

Should be:

`imageButton.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in the UIImage array declaration, the issue might be it not getting an image from the array.

try with this one

```
 var arrImg : [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "res-1")!,UIImage(named: "res-2")!,UIImage(named: "res-3")!]
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RestaurantTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RestaurantTableViewCell
        cell.configureImageButton(with: arrImg[indexPath.row])
        cell.btnResturant.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        cell.configureLabel(with: arrRes[indexPath.row])
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this didn't completely solve my problem, but forcing each UIImage in the array helped take away the error I was getting at cell.configureImageButton(with: myImages[indexPath.row]).Force unwrapping at the end of that line instead also worked, so I did that. When run, the imageButton is showing with the right dimensions (am using a tint for visibility), but the images are not showing in the button. I think my problem lies in my configureImageButton function in TableViewCell.Swift. I think the code is just wrong, particularly either "image", "setImage", or ".normal".

Comment: may be your button outlet is missed because your configureImageButton function is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no, my button outlet is not missed.